# Render Gatsby Page with and without html.js

Tags: gatsby

I want to render each of my Gatsby pages to HTML in two ways

1) without any wrapping content from `html.js`
2) with whatever content is in `html.js`, whether using the default or a custom version I wrote into my repo

This is to allow me to stitch together, client-side, pages from different repositories (different teams sharing the same html.js)

It is equivalent to me to render each page with two different `html.js` files, one with content and one blank.

Is it possible to control this? I can't find any API for this in the Gatsby docs.

Comment: `I think of html.js as the page's layout component` I don't think this is entirely correct. Are you able to add a little bit more about your motivation and what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: It definitely isn't entirely correct, but re-reading this Q I think it may also be irrelevant how I think about it.